# (Xpost from QA) Geb-like Module in Xamarin.UITest?

Tags: xamarin, geb, xamarin.uitest

My understanding of [Geb modules](https://gebish.org/manual/1.0/#repeating-content) was for groups of elements that always appeared together and were recurring throughout the site. Like a nav-bar and header, or a shopping cart.

I'd like to add this module functionality to several pages I'm working on with [Xamarin.UITest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/)

Does anyone know if this is already built in to Xamarin? Has someone already rolled this? Or am I doomed to roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality isn't already build into Xamarin, and no one has focused on building on top of the Xamarin UI Test nuget. You probably have to build that functionality by yourself. If there's anything specific you want help with, feel free to ask, I am sure we can help!